# Not A Blog (George R. R. Martin's blog) has moved

Tags: discussion

George R. R. Martin's "blog", *Not A Blog*, has "recently" [moved away](https://grrm.livejournal.com/566320.html).

> #### NOT A BLOG IS MOVING AWAY...
>
> <sub>Apr. 13th, 2018 at 10:55 AM</sub>
>
> Greetings all,
>
> Minion Raya here to let you know that we're moving the Not A Blog to a whole new location! So if you're looking for the latest news from GRRM hop on over to the website and check out the new Not a Blog:
> http://georgerrmartin.com/notablog/

#### So what do we need to do now?

Well, nothing really I believe I have already gone through the old posts with these links (only 25 or so and the majority were by me anyway). Any post links have been updated to point to the new location. Unfortunately, comments weren't transferred over so posts linking to those now link to archived pages. I may have missed some so if you come across any be sure to update the links as I'm not sure how long the old blog will be active for.

The links inside of the relevant tag wikis have also been updated, I may have missed some in other works of his though.

#### What do we need to be doing in the future?

Pretty simple, link to the new blog where possible or link through to the old one with an archived link. Also keep a lookout for any old posts with the links that weren't updated. Searching for [`url:"*grrm.livejournal*" -url:"*archive.org*"`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=-url%3A%22%2Aarchive.org%2A%22+url%3A%22%2Agrrm.livejournal%2A%22) should yield all posts linking to the old blog but not linking to The Internet Archive, although it misses posts where some but not *all* links have been converted.

Remember though if you are bumping an old post make sure to fix everything you can, including the other answers and/or the question on that page.

Comment: I know meta is more lax on what counts as a 'question', but I don't really understand what this is doing here. You're not calling for any site changes, since you've already made the required edits. Seems like just a PSA about an external website. Might work better as a blog post than a meta? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Randal'Thor It's a post to let users know, who may otherwise not, that links there can die at any point and to use the new location now. I'm not sure of a better way to do this. After all meta is used for announcements and that is essentially what this is.

Comment: Ah, so the links haven't died _yet_ but they will at some point? Fair enough then, I suppose.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well I assume they will at some point as it is no longer supported.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think it *does* relate to the workings of the site in terms of references *to* the external link. It seems very much about the posts on the site. What might be distracting you is that it is pretty much a question and various answers in one, especially since everything has been done already.

Comment: @TARS Think if it this way. This is an announcement post in the same way as the new blog post meta is an announcement.

Comment: The standing rule of thumb is that if it's relevant _to our stack_, then it can be a meta post, even if it's not question. The change of author's blog, and the work needed to update our questions to reflect that, of the author that's inspired nearly 5% of all questions on our stack seems to be relevant to us.

Comment: *grumble grumble [cool URIs don't change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI) grumble grumble*, but the links are probably going to break since no one ever gets this right.  Fixing the links was the right call.

Comment: @Kevin True they may have gotten it right but I'd rather be safe than sorry... especially if we lost content seeing as I had to archive a few links myself